# How to set to value to 0 if max field is empty

Tags: c#, linq, max

I need to use `Max` method in linq, but if max field value is empty I need to show 0 instead. I have this code so far :

```
var groupedData = 
      from b in showit.AsEnumerable()
      orderby b.Field<int>("Key")
      group b by b.Field<int?>("Key") into g
      select new
      {
          KeyName = g.Key,
          date = g.First().Field<string>("date"),
          Team = g.First().Field<string>("Team"),
          Calls_Chats_Answered = g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("Calls_Chats_Answered")),
```

...here I need to get max and set to 0 if max is not found:

```
Max_answering_delay = g.Max(b => b.Field<int?>("Max_answering_delay")),
Max_abandoning_delay= g.Max(b => b.Field<int?>("Max_abandoning_delay")),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetValueOrDefault on the nullable int with a default of 0.(assuming you only have positive values). If none of them has any value, the answer will be 0. Something like this

```
Max_answering_delay = g.Max(b => b.Field<int?>("Max_answering_delay").GetValueOrDefault(0))
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works like Charm !

Comment: @sammybenmenahem You're welcome. Could you, please, mark it as the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty` to get an enumerable containing default (`0`) value if `g` is empty:

```
Max_answering_delay = g.Select(b => b.Field<int>("Max_answering_delay")).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(),
Max_abandoning_delay= g.Select(b => b.Field<int>("Max_abandoning_delay")).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(),
```

Comment: Thanks Arturo , although I didnt tried your answer but the first answer by bbdea Works great ! . Thanks !